# Split array elements containing carriage return

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, element, carriage-return

Start with an array of strings, some of which feature carriage returns:

```
var valArray = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW\nHonda\nAudi","Mazda"];
```

What I want to do is get rid of the carriage return, splitting the string into as many elements as there are carriage returns +1:

```
["Saab","Volvo","BMW","Honda","Audi","Mazda"];
```

What I get with .split:

```
valArray.split("\n");
["Saab","Volvo",["BMW","Honda","Audi"],"Mazda"];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the items to arrays after splitting the carriage returns, then flatten the arrays by applying concat:

```js
var valArray = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW\nHonda\nAudi","Mazda"];

var result = [].concat.apply([], valArray.map(function(item) {
  var items = item.split('\n');
  
  return items;
}));

console.log(result);
```

And another method without a loop:

```js
var valArray = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW\nHonda\nAudi","Mazda"];

var result = valArray.join(',').split('\n').join(',').split(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Tried this and it works very well. Thanks for helping the simple minded!

Comment: You're welcome :) I've added another method without a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the existing array then do something like this using  [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and simple while loop.

```js
var valArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW\nHonda\nAudi", "Mazda"];
var len = valArray.length;

while (len--) {
  [].splice.apply(valArray, [len, 1].concat(valArray[len].split('\n')))
}

console.log(valArray)
```

---

Or if you want a new array then do it using [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method with the help of [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

```js
var valArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW\nHonda\nAudi", "Mazda"];
var len = valArray.length,
  res = [];

while (len--) {
  [].push.apply(res, valArray[len].split('\n'))
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: A much more stylish loop that I was attempting with splice and concat. Thanks! :)